# Can't allocate more than 1 core to a container

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Having an issue allocating more than 1 cpu to a pod that is running code that requires more processing power.

I have set my limit for a container to 3 cpu's
[image]

and have set set the container to request 2 cpu;s with a limit of 3

[image]

But when running the container it does not go over 1000Mi of 1 cpu.

There is very little running during this process and keda will start new nodes if needed.

How can i assign more cpu power to this container?

UPDATE

So i changed the Default Limit as suggested by moonkotte but i can only ever get just over 1 cpu

[image: Limits and defaults]

New Nodes are coming online when more containers are required, through Keda.

each node has 4 cpu, so sufficient resources

this is the details of each node. in this it is running one of the containers in question

[image]

It just isn't using all the cpu allocated

Comment: does whatever process that is running in that container use multi core processing? If the program inside the container is single process/single threaded then it wont use more that 1 core.

Comment: Yes it is multi threading.

Comment: Can you also check 
`kubectl describe node` to see what other containers or system process consumes CPU.
Also can you check if CPU is getting throttled for your container? Exec inside the pod /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/<container> and look for `cpu.stat` file. nr_throttled divided by nr_periods gives throttling percentage.

Comment: @theHaggis Are there any [`LimitRanges`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-default-namespace/)? I can see `Default Limit` is 1 and it may overwrite what you have in manifest.

Comment: Updated original message

Comment: @theHaggis Thank you for update. Not sure why pod doesn't take more than 1000m CPU. You can see that `dev namespace` has 2 cpus and 51% requested of node has. Are you sure your application can use more than 1 core?

Comment: Also new nodes are spawn because on each node there are 4 cpu available (actually a bit less due to [resource reservation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads#resource-reservations)) + other pods running on the node. Your pod has `requests: 2 cpu` there for only 1 pod can be scheduled on one node, it's not enough CPU for the second pod to be scheduled on the same node. Try set `requests` to `1.5` as workaround